# Database Entry not Happening in Flask App with SQL Alchemy?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

**APP CODE** : There is no entry in the database and i am new at Flask and i am not able to connect to database and get entry into it and i am confused is my code is at all right

```
from flask import *
from wtforms import *
from wtforms.validators import Required
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'MY CSI FORM'

branch_choices = [('CSE','CSE'),('ECE','ECE'),('MEC','MEC'),('CIVIL','CIVIL')]
year_choices = [('1st','1st'),('2nd','2nd'),('3rd','3rd'),('4th','4th')]
cmem_choices = [('Yes','Yes'),('No','No')]

class CSIForm(Form):
    er = IntegerField('Enrollment No',validators=[Required()])
    name = StringField('Name', validators=[Required()])
    branch = SelectField('Branch',choices=branch_choices, validators=[Required()])
    year = SelectField('Year',choices=year_choices, validators=[Required()])
    cmem = SelectField('CSI Member',choices=cmem_choices,validators=[Required()])
    sop = TextAreaField('Statement of Purpose', validators=[Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

**DATABASE CODE** : Code for database creation in SQLAlchemy dont know its correct or not

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'

class CSI(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'form'

    er = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30))
    branch = db.Column(db.String(3))
    year = db.Column(db.String(3))
    cmem = db.Column(db.String(3))
    sop = db.Column(db.String(50))

    def __init__(self, er, name, branch, year, cmem, sop):
        self.er = er
        self.name = name
        self.branch = branch
        self.year = year
        self.cmem = cmem
        self.sop = sop

def connect_db():
    db.create_all()
```

App running and connection

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form=CSIForm(request.form)
    connect_db()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        csi = CSI()
        form.populate_obj(csi)
        flash('Thanks for registering')
    return render_template('form.html',form=form)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug='True'
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to read up on [sessions in SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html). You need to add `csi` to your current session and commit the transaction.

```
def index():
    form = CSIForm(request.form)
    connect_db()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        csi = CSI()
        form.populate_obj(csi)

        # These lines are new.
        db.session.add(csi)
        db.session.commit()

        flash('Thanks for registering')
```